# Rails 4: nested attributes and PG::NotNullViolation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a model `User.rb` that `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address`

**user.rb**

```
has_one :address
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

**address.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

When I try to test it using Rails console the following happens

```
user = User.find(157)
```

*User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 157]]*

*#<User id: 157, name: "John Doe", email: ...*

```
user.address.phone
```

*UserAddress Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."type" IN ('UserAddress') AND "addresses"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "addresses"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 157]]

*"1234567"*

That's fine so far. However, the following does not work:

```
user.update(:address_attributes => {:phone  => "888888"})
```

It throws

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

The SQL doesn't make much sense to me

```
UPDATE "addresses" SET "user_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "addresses"."type" IN ('UserAddress') AND "addresses"."id" = 128  [["user_id", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 02 Feb 2014 19:55:07 CET +01:00]]
```

Why does it try to update `user_id` with `nil` when I actually updated the `phone` attribute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is that you're not using the correct `ActiveRecord` object?

Maybe you could try:

```
user.address.update_attributes({phone: "888888"})
```

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes` is meant to update attributes of a direct relation. Using this you can have a form that represents attributes from various models using `fields_for`.

Comment: The question involved the use of `accepts_nested_attributes_for` I think?